# How to create an exe for r code correctly

Tags: r, vbscript, shiny, exe

I would like to let my users use a shiny app that is stored on [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) using `library(shiny);runGist("xxx")`.
For this purpose I've created a folder that contains portable Chrome, portable R and 2 files:

1 - `run.R` - contains the following code:

```
library(shiny);runGist("xxx")
```

2 - VBScript that should call the run.r so the runGist will be invoked.

```vb
Randomize
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave run.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False
```

When I click the VBScript nothing happens so I guess I'm missing something, how can solve this issue?

UPDATE: after clicking the run.vbs I got a numbered file, when I opened it on Notepad++ I got the following text:

```
Downloading https://gist.github.com/#############/download
NULL
[1] TRUE

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:1337
```

When I copied `http://127.0.0.1:1337` to the browser it gives what I want.
So the question is how to invoke the browser with address provided in the message? - I noticed that each click gives another address.

Comment: Somewhat related, see https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR

Comment: get a shiny server.... it worths the effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override default browser option, then `runGist` with `launch.browser` will just work.

**run.R**

```r
#Assuming your portable Chrome's relative path is "Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
options(browser = normalizePath("Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"));

library(shiny);
runGist("xxx", launch.browser = TRUE);
```

**run.vbs**

```vb
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    'specify CD to start commands from script's parent folder
    WshShell.CurrentDirectory = Fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

'Start the command as hidden and don't wait
WshShell.Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave run.R NUL", 0, False
```

Comment: Thank you @Kul-Tigin it works!, I just needed to change the path to Chome portable Installation.One question: I see that after clicking the .vbs file I get some kind of a temp file : i.e radF068D.tmp .Is there a way to skip the creation of this kind of a file.I guess that after a year of usage the folder will contain hundreds of temp files.

Comment: @mql4beginner glad to help. That file wasn't my idea, it's an alternative to your `RND` named file. You can suppress the R's output by using `NUL` instead. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the VBScript point of view, as all you are using are relative paths, if the current active directory (from where relative paths are calculated) is not what you think you can have problems.

You can try with something like (verbose version)

```vbs
Option Explicit

    'Initialize PRNG
    Randomize 

Dim fso 
    ' As we are dealing with files/folders, it is better to use adecuate functions
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim baseFolder
    ' Retrieve the folder where the current script is stored
    baseFolder = fso.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.Path

Dim RScript
    ' Combine the current folder and file to execute 
    RScript = fso.BuildPath( baseFolder, "run.R" )

Dim R
    ' Combine the current folder and path to the R executable
    R = fso.BuildPath( baseFolder, "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe" )

Dim command 
    ' compose the command to execute
    command = q(R) & " CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave " & q(RScript) & " " & Rnd

    ' Execute the composed command
    Call WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run( command, 0, False )

' Just a helper function to quote the file/folder paths in the command    
Function q( text )
    q = """" & text & """"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @MC ND, please see my update, perhaps you can help with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your update:
Note, that you can set the port number as an argument in runApp()
E.g: runApp(..., port = 1337)

Example:

```
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), port = 1337)
```

Edit: Answer to follow-up:

if this does not help:

```
library(shiny);runGist(..., launch.browser = TRUE, port = 1337)
```

try this:

```
library(shiny);runGist(..., port = 1337);browseURL("http://127.0.0.1:1337")
```

Comment: Thank you @Tonio Liebrand, but the problem is how to open the portable Chrome in the address http://127.0.0.1:1337 instead of getting the text : Listening on http://127.0.0.1:1337 inside a file that is generated by the run.vbs

Comment: @mql4beginner: Check my edit. And you should edit your questions in a way that the answers still fit to your question ;)

Comment: Thank for your efforts @Tonio Liebrand, the solution didn't work for me but I'm sure  that some else will find it useful.